# Import ES Module in react native unidentified

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-navigation

I want to import screen to my react navigation but when i import class React.Component its unidentified

my routes.js

```js
import * as Screens from '../screens/index';
import {FontIcons} from '../assets/icons';

export const MainRoutes = [
  {
    id: 'LoginMenu',
    title: 'Marketing',
    icon: FontIcons.login,
    screen: Screens.GridV1,
    children: [
      {
        id: 'Login1',
        title: 'Login V1',
        screen: Screens.GridV1,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 'Login2',
        title: 'Login V2',
        screen: 'GridV2',
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 'SignUp',
        title: 'Sign Up',
        screen: 'GridV2',
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 'password',
        title: 'Password Recovery',
        screen: 'GridV2',
        children: []
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

My screens/index.js

```js
export * from './navigation';
export * from './dash';
```

When i check the Screens import with

```js
console.log(Screens);
```

[image]

Everythings is well. But when i execute

```js
console.log(Screens.GridV1);
```

[image]

i cant reach the GridV1 class

Please help me to solve my problem here. Thanks you

Comment: can you show code of `'../screens/index'`?

Comment: @Val i already give my '../screens/index'. I think nothing wrong with my screens directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your chrome snapshot of `Screens`, it shows that at that moment you `console.log`, `Screens` object only contains one element `{__esModule: true}`. `GridV1`, `GridV2` and all other modules were resolved late with a delay.

Therefore you should see it works with setTimeout, ex:

```js
setTimeout( () => console.log(Screens.GridV1), 100 );
```

But the real problem still hides behind. Normally `import` javascript module won't have such side effect, it should have works as you expected. Check if there are any special initialization mechanism of those modules.